# Jail in chroot in debian 7.5 - Privileges Separation problem

Tags: debian, ssh, chroot, sshd, jails

I'm trying to create a jail for a user in my server. Let's call the user "juser".

What do I want to achieve? I want an ssh user to be jailed in his home folder and not have any access (whatsoever) on my server's root directory.

For that, I'm following the [tutorial given in here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ap-chroot-ssh-env.en.html).

Everything went fine, until the step of Privileges Separation. Now I don't want to disable privilage separation as it is a security threat to the system.

The other solution is in the next line in the tutorial:

> If you don't disable Privilege Separation you will need an /etc/passwd which includes the user's UID inside the chroot for Privilege Separation to work properly.

But I don't know how to do this! In `/etc/passwd` I have for juser:

```
juser:x:5002:5002::/home/juser:/bin/sh
```

How do I implement what is said in the quoted sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Let us say the chroot is in `/path/to/chroot`. Then you need:

1. A directory `etc` in `/path/to/chroot`, and
2. A file called `passwd` in `/path/to/chroot/etc`, with at least one entry:

   ```
   juser:x:5002:5002::/some/path:/some/shell
   ```
3. And both:

   - `/path/to/chroot/some/path`
   - `/path/to/chroot/some/shell`
     (The shell *must* be present, along with any necessary libraries and such.)

Comment: I'm not sure what to do about the shell... should I install a static shell inside that user's chroot?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist If you can get a static binary for the shell, sure. If not, use `ldd` to find the relevant libraries and copy them over as well: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85258/70524

Comment: Should this line be the same one in the root's /etc/passwd? After I set the parameters as you mention, I'm unable to login with the new user at all! ssh fails to login simply with no reason.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist which step does it fail at? Connection? Authentication? Starting the shell?

Comment: Authentication. Could you please tell me what to do with the server root's passwd?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist If it's authentication, then it fails before the chroot is ever reached.

Comment: But I'm adding a new user, and authentication works fine when adding it. After that, when I modify my passwd files, it fails to login.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist modify your passwd files? Did you modify the original host /etc/passwd? What did you change?

Comment: I changed the shell... I chose a script that runs "busybox ash" to start a busybox shell.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19369/discussion-between-muru-and-the-quantum-physicist).